# How to include external libraries when moving my NetBeans project?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I added an external library by adding its .jar file and importing it as a normal import. Now, I want to take the project as a zip file and move it somewhere else. Is it possible to include the .jar file in the zipped file so that I can just open the project in NetBeans at the other PC and run it without the need to add the .jar file manually? I found solutions for including the external library .jar file when we want to build the project .jar file, but I couldn't find a solution for my issue. Sorry if this is a duplicate but I tried hard to find a solution before submitting a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

1. Create a folder named `lib` or whatever name inside your NetBeans project folder.
2. Place the .jar file inside that folder.
3. Add the .jar file to your project from NetBeans.
4. Now the your project is portable with the external library .jar
   file.

Comment: Elaborate your 3rd point like How to add `.jar` file into project? (with screenshot). So for the future visitors it will be more easier to find your post. +1